# Monitor http server

Tags: linux, monitoring, webserver

I want to check the web server health status. If did get http-response in 2 minutes then the server should restart. I am using the below command to check the status -

```
curl -s -w "%{time_total}\n" -o /dev/null http://localhost:8080/demo1/employee/hello
```

But executes the infinite loop and check for a response.

Comment: what is the output of the mentioned curl command ? it gives the output in seconds ? you want to run the curl command infinity times and sleep for every iteration ?

Answer (score 2):

The below script will check the time taken by the url and if it's more than 2 minutes, then it will go inside the if condition. you have to put your restart command there.
It sleeps for 60 seconds for each iteration

```
#!/bin/bash

LOG_FILE=/tmp/log.txt

while true
do
    echo "$(date) - Checking the URL is up or not" >> ${LOG_FILE}
    TIME_TAKEN=$(curl -s -w "%{time_total}\n" -o /dev/null http://localhost:8080/demo1/employee/hello)
    if [ "${TIME_TAKEN}" -gt "120" ]
    then
        echo "$(date) - Restart required. Time taken is ${TIME_TAKEN}" >> ${LOG_FILE}
        # your restart command goes here
        echo "$(date) - Successfully restarted" >> ${LOG_FILE}
    fi
    echo "$(date) - Sleep for 60 seconds" >> ${LOG_FILE}
    sleep 60
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, kamalraj.
How to test the above script. The API (demo1/employee/hello) sends the response after 10 minutes. I intently slept of 10 minutes to test my scenario.  The if-condition will check after 10 minutes.
 
How to test the above script.

Comment: if i understand correctly, your curl command takes 10 minutes to execute the API. so TIME_TAKEN will have the value of 600+ . Then we are checking whether the time taken is greater than 120, then we have to restart the app server